# How to find the optimal solution of a convex program given all KKT points?

Tags: convex-optimization, kkt-conditions, lagrange-multipliers

Suppose we have a parametric convex program with some constraints.
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\max_{x} \: & f(x,\mathbf{a})\\
& g_1(x,\mathbf{a})\le 0 \\
& g_2(x,\mathbf{a}) \le 0
\end{split}
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{a}$ is a vector of parameters. I can obtain all KKT points and their corresponding Lagrangian multipliers. I am wondering if it is possible to find the optimal solution based on KKT points and multipliers by conditioning on them? I mean, I want to find conditions and then say if condition 1 is true, the optimal solution will be the first KKT point, and so on.

Comment: I think for convex program, any KKT point is optimal.

Comment: Crossposted to Math.SE:  [How to find the optimal solution of a convex program given all KKT points?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4226857/572874)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like [parametric programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_programming) to me.

In short, you can calculate a set of regions, typically called "critical regions", within which the same set of constraints is active. This in return enables you to calculate $x$, $\lambda$ and $\mu$ as an explicit function of your parameter $a$.

There are MATLAB tools to do this, most prominently the [POP](https://parametric.tamu.edu/POP/) and [MPT](https://www.mpt3.org/) toolboxes, which support linear and quadratic (mixed-integer) problems.